# Bitwise and arithmetic operations in swift

Tags: swift, bitwise-operators, swift3

Honestly speaking, porting to swift3(from obj-c) is going hard. The easiest but the swiftiest question.

```
public func readByte() -> UInt8
{
    // ...
}

public func readShortInteger() -> Int16
{
    return (self.readByte() << 8) + self.readByte();
}
```

Getting error message from compiler: "Binary operator + cannot be applied to two UInt8 operands."

What is wrong?

ps. What a shame ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readByte` returns a `UInt8` so:

1. You cannot shift a `UInt8` left by 8 bits, you'll lose all its bits.
2. The type of the expression is `UInt8` which cannot fit the `Int16` value it is computing.
3. The type of the expression is `UInt8` which is not the annotated return type `Int16`.

d

```
func readShortInteger() -> Int16
{
    let highByte = self.readByte()
    let lowByte = self.readByte()

    return Int16(highByte) << 8 | Int16(lowByte)
}
```

While Swift have a strictly left-right evaluation order of the operands, I refactored the code to make it explicit which byte is read first and which is read second.

Also an OR operator is more self-documenting and semantic.

Comment: You don't need `var` here, since you're not doing any mutations. :) Also, it would be more idiomatic to simply let type inference do its work with `let highByte = self.readByte()`, rather than doing the type declarations separately.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Oh! Thanks for the improvements!

Comment: Should be signed int8, just missprint. The actual code(CocoaAMF):`- (int16_t)decodeShort{
 [self _ensureLength:2];
 int8_t ch1 = m_bytes[m_position++];
 int8_t ch2 = m_bytes[m_position++];
 return (ch1 << 8) + ch2;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some great Swift documentation on this, here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

```
let shiftBits: UInt8 = 4   // 00000100 in binary
shiftBits << 1             // 00001000
shiftBits << 2             // 00010000
shiftBits << 5             // 10000000
shiftBits << 6             // 00000000
shiftBits >> 2             // 00000001
```